# This code is not returning desired output in geeks for geeks for left view of tree

Tags: c++

This code is not returning desired output in geeks for geeks. for left view of tree

```
vector<int> leftView(Node *root)
{
    vector<int> ans;
    
    if (root==NULL)
        return ans;
    
    else if(root->left==NULL&&root->right!=NULL){
        ans.push_back(root->data);
        leftView(root->right);
    }
    
    else{
        ans.push_back(root->data);
        leftView(root->left);
    }
   return ans;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You never use the return value of the recursive call.

Comment: What is the "desired output"? And to which article do you refer in geeks for geeks? Is this your answer to a question?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your code.

```
vector<int> leftView(Node *root)
{
    vector<int> ans;
    
    if (root==NULL)
        return ans;
    
    else if(root->left==NULL&&root->right!=NULL){
        ans.push_back(root->data);
        leftView(root->right);
    }
    
    else{
        ans.push_back(root->data);
        leftView(root->left);
    }
   return ans;
}
```

It's not clear what this code is even supposed to do, but let's look at what it does.

If you pass in a nullptr, it returns an empty array. That's cool.

If you pass in a node with no left branch but it has a right branch:

1. Put data into ans.
2. Recurse on the right BUT THROW AWAY THE RESULTS.
3. Return ans.

Otherwise, you have a left node, and you do almost the same thing, but you still throw away the results.

So in the end, the only thing you'll return is the data from the root node.

That's probably not what you really want. You probably want to accrue the results. I would pass the vector into the method as a second argument and then keep passing it down. You'll end up getting the data from the root node down the tree to the bottom (sort of). At least it will have more data. If that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When `root` is not NULL, but `root->left` and `root->right` are both NULL, you output nothing. But the `push_back` should be before the `left` and `right` are traversed. More importantly, they should both be traversed, not in an either-or fashion.

Also, when calling `leftView()` recursively, you are ignoring any data it returns.  Which is the main reason your output is not what you are expecting.

Try something more like this instead (based on [this solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-left-view-binary-tree/)):

```cpp
void leftViewHelper(Node *root, int level, int& max_level, std::vector<int> &ans)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
 
    if (max_level < level) {
        ans.push_back(root->data);
        max_level = level;
    }
 
    leftViewHelper(root->left, level + 1, max_level, ans);
    leftViewHelper(root->right, level + 1, max_level, ans);
}
 
vector<int> leftView(Node *root)
{
    vector<int> ans;
    int max_level = 0;
    leftViewHelper(root, 1, max_level, ans);
    return ans;
}
```